# JavaScript subtract two datetimes to seconds

Tags: javascript, datetime

I Need to subtract These datetime in js

```
2018-08-05 20:38:02 // start date
2018-08-17 00:00:00 // end date
```

So that I can later on create a Countdown which tells me the days Hours minutes and second left between These two Dates.

Currently I am not able to correctly subtract those two datetimes, any ideas?

Comment: Why do the many Q&A on StackOverflow on that topic not answer your question??

Comment: @trincot I am asking for a datetime not a date...